# Autofilter with 3 x xlOr criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

So I’m trying to filter a Report sheet on the first (day of week) column to display all Saturday, Sunday and Monday lines.  The code I am using is getting a `Application-defined or object-defined error` and will not run.  I think it has something to do with using 3 x `lxOr` parts in my code.  Any advice is welcome on how to fix this?

```
Sub FilterDays()

With Sheets("Report")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Saturday", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Field:=1, Criteria2:="Sunday", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Field:=1, Criteria3:="Monday"
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t have more than 2 criteria by using `Autofilter xlOr`. If you searched SO you would have found plenty of examples on here of using an Array to filter `xlOr` on more than 2 values.  In your own case, the following should work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterDays()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Report")

With ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 1, Array("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"), 7
End With

End Sub
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That worked really well, thank you :)